# Get a value of an attribute in XML, but of what element is determined by a value of another attribute in Go

Tags: xml, go

In the following example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
)

var data = `
<data>
    <text id="0" action="wake"/>
    <text id="1" action="eat"/>
    <text id="2" action="bathe"/>
    <text id="3" action="walk"/>
</data>
`

type Result struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"data"`
    Action string //this is the part I want to solve
}


func main() {
    res := Result{}
    xml.Unmarshal(data, &res)
    fmt.Printf("%#v", res)
}
```

I want to get is the following struct:

```
{XMLName: xml.Name{Space:"", Local:"data"}, Action:"eat"}
```

So can I get the value of `action` attribute on the fourth `text` element only? In other words, I want to get the value of an attribute of any arbitrary elements, but that element is decided by another attribute within that element (`id=3` in this case).

One thing to solve the issue is to embed another struct which holds each `text` element as slices, and iterate over that slice and if the `id` field is `3`, then I get that inner struct's `action` field... but it's too daunting and ineffective to process.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything here http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal  that would filter text where id is not 3.  You *could* wrap Unmarshal to add the filter.  As a side note, you'll want to cast data to []byte when unmarshalling in the main().

Answer (score 0):

Unmarshal unmarshals XML to a struct. It is not called XPath because you cannot do what you want with Unmarshal.

Either unmarshal into a larger struct and iterate until id==3 as you suggested. (Not sure why you say this is inefficient. And I doubt that you measured the cost of doing before claiming inefficiency).

Or: Parse the XML manually with xml.Decoder and processing the Tokens yourself.